# If an 'if' statement is true, add it to the list of true ones, else ignore it

Tags: php, regex, if-statement

I'm trying to make a matching thing if the 'if' statement like this:

```
$name = "how"; // <<<this is an input
if(preg_match(  "/(How|my|brain|works)/i",$name)){
    $result1= "this is one of the results";
}else{
    $result1= " ";
```

I'm planning to store the results that if there's an actual match, it would display the first message, it might sometimes be pictures.

The problem is how I can make it so that when I later do the match and if it's not true it wouldn't have a blank page. How can I skip over it. If for example I'm doing a list and there's about 5 that match with the input, it would display the 5 input instead of showing 10 list. The list would probably look like this

```
<ul>
  <li><?php echo $result1 ?></li>
  <li><?php echo $resutl2 ?></li>
  <li><?php echo $match10    // and so on ?></li>
</ul>
```

How can I make it so that it skips over for example match 9 because it's equal to space or display it because it's not equal to space. The problem is that it would list out all 3 and if match9 is equal to space, it would display space and I want it to skip over those.

Comment: This question Needs More Focus -- it is asking too many questions.  We don't have a good, clean [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array instead of separate variables, and only add to the array when you get a match.

```
$results = array();

$name = "how"; // <<<this is an input
if(preg_match(  "/(How|my|brain|works)/i",$name)){
    $results[] = "this is one of the results";
}
```

Then when you're displaying the results:

```
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($results as $r) {
    echo "<li>$r</li>\n";
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: One question, how can i display that in a slideshow. when clicked 'next', it would go to the next one. this would really help out my website

Comment: Use a plugin that turns the `<ul>` into a slideshow. I don't know which one to recommend, I'm not really familiar with them.